# adding a control to tabs generated dynamically in tabcontrol in C# .net

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls, tabcontrol

I am new to C# .NET.

Can some one help me out with the below problem:

I have a TabControl in my WindowsForm application, where the tab pages are generated dynamically. The content to be displayed on each tab would be fetched from my database. I need some kind of control (which can display the fetched data) that I can add on each tab page (which would be same for all tabs) such that I can associate some kind of event, say click, on that added control.

Can anyone tell me how to do this programmatically & write the click event for all the controls added?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer the below link! You will get more detail in this regard.

[Creating a tab control with a dynamic number of tabs in Visual Studio C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084098/creating-a-tab-control-with-a-dynamic-number-of-tabs-in-visual-studio-c)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem but my initial thoughts are that you could dynamically create a datagrid or something similar for each tab that you are dynmically creating. You could then bind the datasource for the grid and then add the grid as a control to your tabpage.

Something like...

```
DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();
gv.DataSource = //whatever your source is            
this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(gv);
```

You would then have all the events associated with the grid to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking data binding is going to be your best bet for displaying this information. You can create a list of objects and use a DataTemplate to format the data. You can apply the DataTemplate to a quite a few objects. I generally use the ItemsControl and ListBox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx

good luck

Comment: You missed the "winforms" part of his quesiton